# Trying to get property of non-object -> how can I check Object Exists

Tags: javascript, php, dom, domdocument

How can I check to see if an object exists when using Dom Document as I'm getting the

> error "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
$getplacename            = '//table//tr';
$getplacename2           = $xpath->query($getplacename);
//loop through each individual card
foreach($getplacename2 as $getplacename22) {

echo  $getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(2)->textContent;
echo  $getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(4)->textContent;
echo "<br /><br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: whatever property you think might / might not exist you should first perform a empty check on it. if(!empty($getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(2)->textContent)) echo $getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(2)->textContent;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that easiest way to do such thing is to change code to something like this (assuming that error occurred in one of following lines):

```
foreach($getplacename2 as $getplacename22) {
    if ($getplacename22->childNodes->item(0) != null && $getplacename22->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(2) != null) {
        echo $getplacename22->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(2)->textContent;
    }
    if($getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(4) != null) {
        echo $getplacename22->childNodes->item(4)->textContent;
    }
    echo "<br /><br /><br />";
}
```